# Как закрыть менюшку?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Не понимаю, что я делаю не так, мне нужно чтоб при открытой менюшке, я мог её закрыть по клику на "Меню" и по клику на область вокруг самой менюшки, уже потрачен час)) хелп)

```js
$('.open').click(function() {
  if($('.open').hasClass('is-active')) {
    $('.open').removeClass('is-active');
    $('.my-block').removeClass('active');
    console.log('remove Class');
  } else {
    $('.open').addClass('is-active');
    $('.my-block').addClass('active');
  }
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e){
    let div = $('.my-block');

    if (!div.is(e.target) && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
      div.removeClass('active');
      $('.open').removeClass('is-active');
    } else {}
  });
```

```css
.main {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.open {
   cursor: pointer;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 5;
}
.open.is-active {
  color: red;
}
.my-block.active {
  right: 0;
}
.my-block {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: auto;
  right: -150px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="open">меню</div>

  <div class="my-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad impedit, laborum id rerum eveniet porro necessitatibus ullam culpa nostrum ipsam!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчик события *mouseup* срабатывает раньше чем *click* и тем самым мешает правильно отработать обработчику *click*

```js
$('.open').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('.open').toggleClass('is-active');
  $('.my-block').toggleClass('active');
});

$('.my-block').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
})

$('.main').click(function() {
  $('.open').removeClass('is-active');
  $('.my-block').removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
.main {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.open {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}

.open.is-active {
  color: red;
}

.my-block.active {
  right: 0;
}

.my-block {
  width: 130px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 30px;
  height: auto;
  right: -150px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="open">меню</div>

  <div class="my-block">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad impedit, laborum id rerum eveniet porro necessitatibus ullam culpa nostrum ipsam!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Моя ошибка, забыл уточнить, плюс ко всему мне нужно, чтоб при клике на голубую область при открытом меню, оно  так же закрывалось

Comment: Добавил в код ответа